# Constraint violation in a trusted constraint

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, constraint

I have a table with a constraint on it that has an existing record that is in violation of that constraint.  While this is possible if someone applied the constraint without a check and after violation data was inserted, how would it be possible that the is_not_trusted flag is zero in the sys.foreign_keys table?

This is the situation I currently have, a data violation on a foreign key where the is_not_trusted flag is zero.  I thought that was essentially the flag that confirms whether the constraint has been enforced 'religiously'.

Thanks

Comment: This might happen due to the the value physically written on the page being incorrect (data corruption). 

Or a bug in the product (probably less likely but [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7772308/73226)).

Run `DBCC CHECKDB` to see if that finds any issues.

Comment: Along Martin's comment - did the data get into the table via `MERGE`? [Here is one bug (closed as "Won't Fix") that can do exactly this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/699055/merge-query-plans-allow-fk-and-check-constraint-violations), and [another bug (also "Won't Fix")](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). If you need more reasons to avoid `MERGE`, see [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

This might happen due to the the value physically written on the page being incorrect (data corruption). Or a bug in the product (probably less likely but [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771869/is-this-a-bug-in-merge-failing-to-implement-foreign-key-properly/7772308#7772308)). Run `DBCC CHECKDB` to see if that finds any issues. – Martin Smith Jun 18 '16 at 0:07
3

Along Martin's comment - did the data get into the table via `MERGE`? [Here is one bug (closed as "Won't Fix") that can do exactly this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/699055/merge-query-plans-allow-fk-and-check-constraint-violations), and [another bug (also "Won't Fix")](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). If you need more reasons to avoid `MERGE`, see [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). – Aaron Bertrand♦ Jun 18 '16 at 3:21